# Refresh animate component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

When app is beginning I have an animation table that moving from left to right width delay on the next row and I want to have this effect every time when user selects another country in this example. But for this moment this effect working only one time when is chosen the first country from list. My goal is to set this animation on every select. How Can I do this one, something with useEffect or other solution?
Effect on this link from codesanbox
https://8xs9u.csb.app/

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {data} from './data';

export default function App() {
  const [countrySelect, setCountrySelect] = useState('');

  let countries = ['Spain', 'Germany', 'England'];
  const optionCountry = countries.map((country, index) => (
    <option value={country} key={index}>
      {country}
    </option>
  ));

  const selectCountry = (e) => {
    setCountrySelect(e.target.value);
  };

  const showTable = data
  .filter(item => item.country === countrySelect)
  .map((item,index) => 
    <tr className='move' style={{animationDelay: `${index / 2}s` }}>
      <td>{item.city}</td>
      <td>{item.pop}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className="select">
        Show country:
        <select onChange={selectCountry}>{optionCountry}</select>
      </div>
      <table className="table">
        <tr>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Pop</th>
        </tr>
        {showTable}
      </table>
    
    </div>
  );
}


.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  margin: auto;
}
tr.move {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: animate 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this is a really weird way
Add class move2 which is copy of move and keyframes animate2 for this class and state show that changing true/false state when selectCountry() is executed.
It is working but I'm not sure that this is a good solution

Adding code:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
const selectCountry = (e) => {
    setCountrySelect(e.target.value);
    setShow(!show);
  };
...
<tr
        className={show ? "move" : "move2"}
        style={{ animationDelay: `${index / 2}s` }}
  >
```